# ActionRecord Not Found. Couldn't find with id=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Caracal Gem to export a Docx file, the gem is generating the document normally. But when I try to print the contract data I get the error. It's probably some routing problem, I'm stuck in this two weeks and I'm almost giving up. 
The error is Action Record Not Found Couldn't fid contrato with id= 
Here is my code I highlighted the parts in the code. 
Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'grayscale/index'
  get 'contratos/page'  HERE IS THE ROUTING

  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'registrar'}
  resources :contratos

  root 'contratos#index'
  get '/contrato_export' => 'contratos#export'
  resources :contratos do
    member do
      # /contratos/:id/export
      get 'export'
    end
  end

end
```

contratos_controller.rb

```
 before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_contrato, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :export]
  access all: [:show, :index], user: {except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit]}, site_admin: :all
  require './lib/generate_pdf'

  def page
    contrato = Contrato.find(params[:id])<---HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!!!

    Caracal::Document.save(Rails.root.join("public", "example.docx")) do |docx|
      docx.style do
        id 'Body'
        name 'body'
        font 'Times New Roman'
        size 24
      end

      docx.h2 'Contrato'
      docx.p do
        style 'Body'
        text 'Lorem ipsun dolor sit amet'
        text contrato.day <--- HERE IS THE DATA THAT I WANT TO PRINT IN THE DOCX. (IN THE CONTRATO SHOW is @contrato.day, I WANT THAT DATE TO BE PRINTED.
        end
    end
    path = File.join(Rails.root, "public")
    send_file(File.join(path, "example.docx"))
  end
```

Comment: I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJPJDzElsfk&t=277s

Comment: i think you need to add `:id` to the route, like `get 'contratos/:id/page'`

Comment: Appear the error: Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.

Comment: ok, why don't you try adding `get 'page'` below `get 'export'` and comment out the other route?

Comment: These are the routing for the Prawn Gem to generate a PDF.

Comment: can you share the `URL` that you are requesting ?

Comment: The Show URL: http://localhost:3000/contratos/1 and the docx url: http://localhost:3000/contratos/page  Seems like that the button to export the docx is not getting the contract id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing `params`

```
  get 'contratos/:id/page', to: 'contratos#page'

#or

  resources :contratos do
    member do
      get 'export' # /contratos/:id/export

      get 'page' # add this!
    end
  end
```

Comment: You have to use `get 'contratos/:id/page', to: 'contratos#page'` as the controller and action can't be derived from that path.

Comment: @max Yeah, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial is just utter garbage. You can do the exact same thing (or at least what I think your trying to do) RESTfully without adding any additional routes just by using [ActionController::MimeResponds](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html):

```
class ContratosController < ApplicationController
  # GET /contratos/1
  # GET /contratos/1.pdf
  # GET /contratos/1.docx
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.pdf { send_file Contratos::PdfConverter.call(@contrato) } 
      format.docx { send_file Contratos::XMLConverter.call(@contrato) } 
    end
  end
end
```

The key here is keep your controller skinny. Controllers are notoriously hard to test.

We haven't actually declared `Contratos::PdfConverter` yet but this is one place where you could just use the [service object pattern](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial):

```
# app/services/base_service.rb
class BaseService
  def self.call(*args, **kwargs, &block)
    new(*args, kwargs, &block)
  end
end
```

```
# app/services/contratos/docx_converter.rb
module Contratos
  class DocxConverter < BaseService
    # @return [Pathname]
    def call(contrato)
      path = Rails.root.join("public", "example.docx")
      Caracal::Document.save(path) do |docx|
        docx.style do
          id 'Body'
          name 'body'
          font 'Times New Roman'
          size 24
        end
        docx.h2 'Contrato'
        docx.p do
          style 'Body'
          text 'Lorem ipsun dolor sit amet'
          text contrato.day # ...
        end
      end
      path
    end
  end
end
```

```
# app/services/contratos/pdf_converter.rb
module Contratos
 class PdfConverter < BaseService
   def call(contrato)
     # generate PDF here
   end
 end
end
```

This lets you test the conversion separately and avoids turning your controller into a flaming garbage pile.

Comment: I'm not saying this is a copy paste answer that will fix all your woes but it should give you at least a much improved starting point.

Comment: Ok, lemme see, I created the services folder in /app/services and then I created the file BaseService.rb inside the folder and then I paste the code. So I need to create a new file for the Docx? And one question, how do I call the docx to convert my html when there is no routes?

Comment: I added annotations for the file paths "how do I call the docx to convert my html when there is no routes?" There is a route. It all just goes through the normal `GET /contratos/:id` route declared by `resources :contratos`. You can link to specific formats by passing the `format:` option. `link_to 'PDF', contrato_path(contrato, format: :pdf)` - `link_to 'Word Document', contrato_path(contrato, format: :docx)`. This just adds an extension to the path.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting a syntax error syntax error when mapping my button to export docx file. The error is: unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' , syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')', syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'

Comment: That's an extremely generic error and there is not really that much I can do to help you there. Follow the stack trace to the line in question and it should not be that hard to fix.